# Is it possible to set GLSL variables in between operations?

Tags: opengl, glsl

I am aiming at the following case:

```
bind shader
set uniform variable
..draw box..
set uniform variable to different value
..draw another box, with the new variable applied in the vertex shader..
```

Is it possible to set GLSL variables in between operations?

Comment: I don't understand the question. It sounds like you're asking if command B, issued after command A, will use data set by command A. But that [seems too obvious to ask about](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Memory_Model).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can freely set uniforms after compilation and mix the settings with draw calls.